# Is $x \in X$ isolated iff the ideal $M_x := \{f \in C(X, \mathbb R) :f(x)=0\}$ of $C(X, \mathbb R)$ is principal ?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, metric-spaces, continuity, ideals

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space , then is $x \in X$ isolated iff the ideal $M_x := \{f \in C(X, \mathbb R) :f(x)=0\}$ of $C(X, \mathbb R)$ is principal ? Do we need completeness of $X$ ?

Comment: One direction is easy: if $x$ is isolated then $M_x=(g)$ where $g=1_{X \backslash \{x\}}$

Comment: For the other direction use Urysohn's lemma, maybe?

Comment: @Shalop : What is $1_{X \setminus \{x\}}$ ?

Comment: The function which is 0 at $x$ and 1 everywhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $R:=C(X, \mathbb R)$, since for each $f\in R$, $f=\sqrt[3]{f}\cdot\sqrt[3]{f}^2$, we have $M_x^2=M_x$. Suppose $M_x$ is principal, say $M_x=(g)$, then $g=g^2h$ for a certain $h\in R$, thus $M_x=(gh)$ and $(gh)^2=gh$, which forces that $gh$ takes value $0$ or $1$ everywhere, in particular, $f$ vanishes in a neighborhood of $x$. If $x$ is not isolated, that leads a contradiction.

Comment: why is $(gh)^2=gh$ ?

Comment: @SaunDev Because $g=g^2h$, multiplying by $g$ on both side, we get $gh=g^2h^2=(gh)^2$

Comment: Why does $f$ vanish in a neighborhood of $x$ and why does it lead to a contradiction if $x$ is not isolated ?

Comment: @SaunDev Because $gh(x)=0$ and $gh$ is continuous, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $|gh(y)-gh(x)|=|gh(y)|\in(-0.5,0.5)$ for all $y\in V$. At the same time $gh(z)=0$ or $1$ for all $z\in R$, thus $\forall y\in V,\  gh(y)=0$. Since $gh$ generates $M_x$, all elements in $M_x$ vanishes in  a **fixed** neighborhood $V$ of $x$. On the other hand,  if $x$ is not isolated, then for each neighborhood $W$ of $x$, we can find a function $f$ which only vanishes in a neighborhood of $x$ that is strictly smaller than $W$, that's a contradiction.

Comment: To show that $f$ vanishes only in a neighborhood strictly smaller than $V=B(x, \epsilon)$ I was thinking of considering the closed ball $B[x, \epsilon /2 ]$ and the closed set $X \setminus B(x,\epsilon)$ these are disjoint . To apply Urysohn's lemma I must conclude that    $X \setminus B(x,\epsilon)$ is non-empty , how do I do that ?

Comment: @SaunDev You are only considering metric spaces,  why not use the metric function $d$? Note that $f:X\to\mathbb R, y\mapsto\max(d(y,x)-\epsilon,0)$ only vanishes at $\overline{B(x, \epsilon)}$.

Comment: Do you mean $\epsilon /2$ instead of $\epsilon$ because you want to make the vanishing interval smaller than $B(x,\epsilon)$ ; but the question remains , are there at all any points in $B(x,\epsilon)$ out side $B[x,\epsilon /2]$ ?

Comment: @SaunDev If $x$ is not isolated, $V-\{x\}$ cannot be empty. Choose any $x^\prime\in V-\{x\}$. Then any $\epsilon<d(x^\prime,x)$ works.